# Android: TransactionTooLargeException but bundle size is just 368

Tags: android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate, transactiontoolargeexception

Finally, I was able to replicate `TransactionTooLargeException` in my app

I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show few fragments, Each fragment hosts a RecycleView and on click of each Item another fragment is being added.

On pressing Home button in while recyclerView screen is on foreground app crashes

This is how `saveState` looks like in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
 @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                return null;
            }
```

If I try to log bundle size it appears around 300 Kb but logcat shows 966576 Kb

Just to make sure this is only bundle that makes app crash If I make it null before **super** app won't crash

Wondering where my fragments are trying to save to OS Process

Comment: Does it only happens when you are debugging?

Comment: @Sagar Happens on Prod as well